# Creating a Javascript Variable with the Length of an Array

Tags: javascript, rename

In this function I need to create a new variable called "dorfX". X is the length of the array the variable would go in. For instance, this would produce a variable called "dorf5" with the parameters specified in the function "makeADorf". However, it doesn't want to work because the name of the variable isn't identified.

From what I can tell, either I need to rename the variable somehow or figure out how to make this work.

This probably has a simple answer, but I'm pretty new to programming and I would be really grateful if I could get some help. Thanks.

```
function guildRecruit(){
    var price = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1) + (dorves.length*50);
    var recruit = prompt("Hello there friend. Would you like to recruit an adventurer?");
    if(recruit == "yes"){
        var dorf(dorves.length) = new makeADorf("Testificate","123");
        dorf(dorves.length).push(dorf(dorves.length));
    }else{
        confirm("Thank you for visiting the Dragon Slayer Guild.");
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you wrote does not make a lot of sense. Are you trying to create a variable with a number at the end of it?

Comment: Why would you ever want a variable with variable name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are a little confused on how to set up your code. Guessing from what you wrote, it looks like you want a function that either:

- Creates a new dorf / adventurer and remembers it
- Does nothing other than write a message

To do this you probably want to create an array outside the function. I'll refer to the array as "adventurers". If the condition to make a new dorf is true, then you push the new dorf to the "adventurers" array. Something like this (note: I removed any code that uses dorves):

```
var adventurers = []; // new Array(); would do the same thing, read Jan Dvorak's comment
function guildRecruit() {
    var price = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
    var recruit = prompt("Hello there friend. Would you like to recruit an adventurer?");
    if (recruit == "yes") adventurers.push(new makeADorf("Testificate","123"));
    else confirm("Thank you for visiting the Dragon Slayer Guild.");
}
```

**Edit**: I can't think of a case where creating variables with numbers would be useful. I also am fairly certain it is not possible to do so. The point of an array is to use logic that would be similar to that but your dorves would be referenced like `adventurers[0]` instead of `adventurers(someFunction)`.

Comment: don't use `new Array()`! Use `[]`. It's faster, and `new Array(int)` doesn't do quite the same as `[int]`.

Comment: Jan Dvorak's point is true, if arrays make sense to you, use his suggestion.

Comment: My comment is targeted to you, asimes. _You_ should fix `new Array` in your code.

Comment: I think slight optimizations can wait until after he understands what code is / should be doing.

Comment: this is not a slight optimisation. `new Array()` is code smell, if only because `new Array(content)` works except when `content` is a single number. It's much easier to fix this _now_ than change his ways later.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. When I wrote it I was a tad tired from a big program. I'll have to rewrite it. Thanks again.